# Access db data in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In Cloud Functions for Firebase, for example:

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onWrite(event => {
    //how to access data at another node, for example 
    //important/messages/{pushId}
})
```

How to do I read data at another node, for example `/important/messages/{pushId}`? Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original').onWrite(event => {
   const getSomethingPromise = admin.database().ref(`/important/messages/{pushId}`).once('value');
   return getSomethingPromise.then(results => {
            const somethingSnapshot = results[0];
            // Do something with the snapshot
        })
    })
```

Check this example for instance: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js

Comment: How can you read the remaining data on the node `/messages/{pushId}/original`!?  Example if you wanted to read the remaining data on the path `/messages/{pushId}/`

Comment: `event.data.val()` will give you the data in the `/messages/{pushId}/original` node