# How to implement json object in Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to verify apple in app purchase receipt by sending the original receipt to App store server for validation and get validated receipt back, using Firebase cloud functions.

```
var jsonObject = {
            'receipt-data': receiptData,
            password: functions.config().apple.iappassword
        };
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
        var firebaseRef = '/' + fbRefHelper.getUserPaymentInfo(currentUser);

        let url = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";//or production  
        request.post({
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            url: url,
            body: jsonData
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {

            } else {
                var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(body);
                if (jsonResponse.status === 0) {
                    console.log('Recipt Valid!');

                } else {

                    console.log('Recipt Invalid!.');

                }
                if (jsonResponse.status === 0 && jsonResponse.environment !== 'Sandbox') {
                    console.log('Response is in Production!');
                }
                console.log('Done.');
            }
        });
```

This is the logic code. How do i input the receipt JSON object (which is sitting in the Firebase database) and how do i integrate this code in an http function? I am using 'request' npm library.

Comment: What specific problem are you running into trying to create an HTTP function?

Comment: I am not sure how to fetch the receipt that i have stored for each user on the realtime firebase database. If i use database cloud function .onwrite() or .onupdate() i am able to access the receipt using db .ref('Customers/{uid}/receiptData') and use event.data to get the receipt and then pass it in to this logic. however, with http function, I am not able to find documentation to do such thing. Also, as i am new to node.js, i am struggling to understand the flow and structure of the http cloud function. Specifically, how can i implement this logic code.

Comment: You'll typically use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) in your Cloud Functions code to access the database. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43650472/access-db-data-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment, it sounds as if you don't know how to query the database from within an HTTPS type function.  You can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) for this.  There are [lots of examples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) of how to do this.  In particular, this [uppercase quickstart sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/uppercase) illustrates it.  You start like this:

```
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Comment: referring to this:                                                                       'exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onWrite(event => {
     const getSomethingPromise = admin.database().ref(`/important/messages/{pushId}`).once('value');

     return getSomethingPromise.then(results => {
        const somethingSnapshot = results[0];

        // Do something with the snapshot
    })
}) '  I am a bit confused. Doesnt **.onwrite()** mean access of data when the event of writing data takes place?? Am i able to query db in http func?