# How to Access Firebase Database Inside a Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

In the code below:

```
exports.sendRequestNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{notificationid}/longitude').onWrite((event) => {
    const lat = admin.database().ref('/Users/B8r1Xc8cAOVGOiptlFOz45fzxSm1');
    return Promise.all([lat]).then((results) =>{
        const latitud = results[0];
        console.log('hi   ',latitud.data.child('name').val());
    });
});
```

I'm trying to get the name of a specific user and log it out but it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined
at Promise.all.then (/user_code/index.js:60:35)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

I tried the solution at this post and it didn't work too ([Access db data in Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43650472/access-db-data-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase))

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 4):

admin.database().ref() doesn't return a promise.  It just returns a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference) object.  If you want to query the data at the location of the reference, use its [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) method.  once() returns a promise that's resolved when the data is available:

```
admin.database().ref('/Users/B8r1Xc8cAOVGOiptlFOz45fzxSm1').once('value')
.then(snapshot => {
    // use the object returned here to get the data at the location of the ref
    snapshot.val()
})
```