# What happens when I use .on() in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

If I do not use .off() in particular to shut down the event listener, will it be turned off automatically when the http request has been processed?

So when a user browses http://www.example.com/organisations and I retrieve the data with an .on() call like:

`admin.database().ref('organisations').on('child_added', snap...)`

What happens with that connection when the request is done and the user got his data? Since I don't close the event listener with .off() I should assume Cloud Functions is still listening to the `child_added` event? But on the other hand that wouldn't make any sense for an http-request, so I could also assume that Firebase closes all event listeners after the request has been processed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't call `off()` to stop a listener that was started by `on()`, it will not turn off.  You may be billed for the bandwidth it consumes until the allocated server instance shuts down.

**Use of on() in Cloud Functions is almost never the right thing to do**.

You should probably just be calling once() at the location of your data and use it when it's ready.

Comment: Thanks. I know using `.on()` doesn't make sense in Cloud Functions but I want to retrieve a list and I thought that using `.once('value')` might be the wrong way.

Comment: `.once('value')` and then `snapshot.forEach...` push each child to an array and then response the array in the body @Fortuna

Comment: `once()` gives you everything under the requested location.  You can do whatever you want with the data after that.

Comment: I'd consider this a pretty idiomatic example of how to retrieve "other" data in Cloud Functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43650799